# 'int' object is not subscribtable

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I have the following python code to obtain the nth fiboncacci number. I think it should work. Only thing is that when I try to run it in my linux terminal, I get an error message that says 'int' object is not subscritable. I cannot see what the bug is. I have sat her for almost an hour trying to debug it.

```
import sys

def fibo(n):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    for i in range(n):
        x = x+y
        y = y+x
        results = x,y

    if n%2==0:
        print(results[int(n//2)][1])
    else:
        print(results[int(n//2)][2])

def main():
    var  = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(fibo(var))
main()
```

Comment: `results = x, y` so `results[int(n//2)]` is always going to be one of `x` or `y` (Or out of bounds). `0[1]` doesn't mean anything, so you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a result of you trying to subscript an int when you print an answer. Try this:

```
import sys

def fibo(n):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    results = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = x+y
        y = y+x
        results.append((x,y))

    if n%2==0:
        print(results[int(n//2)][0])
    else:
        print(results[int(n//2)][1])

def main():
    var  = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(fibo(var))
main()
```

Comment: You'll notice that the answer that it outputs is wrong. I'll leave it up to you to fix the logic of the problem.

Comment: So the variable results is an array with sub-arrays. Each of the subarrays has two elements. What I'm trying to do is call an element within a sub-array. I assume if you had x = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6] and you wanted to call 3 you would use x[2][0] right?

Comment: The variable results is just a tuple being reassigned a  new value every iteration

Comment: Yeah and each of the tuples is an array with two elements. The first element in each tuple is an nth fibonacci number where n is an even number. The second element of each tuple is an nth fibonacci number where n is odd. I hope that makes sense. If I can merge all these arrays into one, then I would have all consecutive fibonacci numbers

Comment: What i'm saying is every time you call "results = x,y" it overwrites the previous tuple. Try what I've changed above.

Comment: O!! I see what you're saying. I should store my results in a variable so that they're not lost at every iteration :)

Comment: Yes, exactly! Now it will have something to double index.

Comment: Alright. I am not quite at the final solution yet but this was definitely a step forward! Thanks